# Month and date position got interchanged after using Data conversion

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, data-conversion

I am trying to load some data from a `.csv` file into my SQL Server. There is a column for date which has datatype Unicode (WSTR) in the `.csv` file and the column for storing that date in SQL Server is of `Datetime` data type.

When I used DATA CONVERSION transformation to convert WSTR data to DBTIMESTAMP data, it got changed but with an error that it interchanged the month and date which gives me the wrong date.

The date should be like 2019-09-03 (for 3rd Sep 2019), but I get 2019-03-09.

Please suggest what the issue is that I am facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

This may occurs when converting a string to a date value without specifying the date format. Reffering to the [SSIS data conversion transformation official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/data-conversion-transformation?view=sql-server-2017):

> If you are converting data to a date or a datetime data type, the date in the output column is in the ISO format, although the locale preference may specify a different format.

Assume that the data is stored in the csv file with the following date format `MM/dd/yyyy` and the default date format in the regional settings is `dd/MM/yyyy` then date values will not be converted properly.

### Solution

In order to specify the date format you have to use a Script Component or a Derived column.

**Derived Column**

You have to reorder the date part manually, you can use `TOKEN()` and `TOKENCOUNT()` function to do that, the following expression convert `dd/MM/yyyy` format into `yyyy-MM-dd` universal format:

```
TOKEN([DateColumn],"/",3) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN([DateColumn],"/",2),2) + "-" +RIGHT("0" + TOKEN([DateColumn],"/",1),2)
```

**Script Component**

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` function to parse a date based on a specific format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Row.DateColumn,"MM/dd/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture");
```